# Drag and drop fail when called via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two pages with the similar codes. One is here http://183.78.169.53/tm/addTyreSwap1.php in this page you have select the vehicle via the drop down list then a number of tyre will appear via the ajax call. The problem is that both the draggable and droppable is attached to it but is not working. On the other hand I have another page http://183.78.169.53/tm/getTyreLayoutDetails1.php?l=3 here which directly generate the tyre layout and both drag n drop works perfects fine. Both are using the same codes. Only one is via ajax. Any idea why it fails in ajax?

Answer (score 1):

you are not using the same code in both the cases
in the [second](http://183.78.169.53/tm/getTyreLayoutDetails1.php?l=3) case you have `<span class="droppable ui-droppable">` where as in the [first](http://183.78.169.53/tm/addTyreSwap1.php) case you have `<span class="droppable">`

Comment: Dear Kranthi, I know and saw before in the inspect element. To my surprise both the pages have the same php codes. Part of the codes is this echo "<div class='t1'>";      
       echo "<span class=\"droppable\">";
              echo "<b>".$loPosition."</b>";
              echo "<img class=\"draggable\" src=\"tyreImages/tyre2.png\" >";
        echo "</span>";

Comment: Dear Kranthi, So website say that for the first case I must reassign the droppable and draggable function. I do not how to to that any help on that?

Comment: The HTML you see in inspect element or any other tool is the output of PHP. In the [second](http://183.78.169.53/tm/getTyreLayoutDetails1.php?l=3) case PHP is not echoing `<span class="droppable ui-droppable">` but in the [first](http://183.78.169.53/tm/addTyreSwap1.php) it is echoing `<span class="droppable">`

Comment: Ok kranthi I have a new link http://183.78.169.53/tm/addTyreSwap2.php now where is show<span class="droppable ui-droppable"> but both drag n drop working not as it suppose to be.